# 'python manage.py createsuperuser' error

Tags: python, django

The 'python manage.py createsuperuser' command gives me this error:

> Superuser creation skipped due to not running in a TTY. You can run `manage.py createsuperuser` in your project to create one manually.

Looking through the source, namely createsuperuser.py, it catches the NotRunningInTTYException:

```
except NotRunningInTTYException:
    self.stdout.write(
        "Superuser creation skipped due to not running in a TTY. "
        "You can run `manage.py createsuperuser` in your project "
        "to create one manually."
    )
```

Anyone know how I can resolve this error? if it makes any difference, my installation process was a headache... getting 'python manage.py runserver' took me a good day. Maybe I don't have things configured properly... Using Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you tried to run this inside an IDE or some other environment which is not a TTY. Django expects the command to be run from a TTY compatible shell.

Run the command on your Windows command prompt, outside your editor/IDE. It should work.

To know more about TTY:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/481906/what-does-tty-stand-for
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con
- http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/

Comment: I am running the command inside Git Bash command line. I'm using PyCharm IDE however I'm not using the terminal it provides.

Comment: Can you please try Windows Prompt without Git bash?

Comment: Ahhh awesome that one works! Hmm, why isn't it working with Git Bash? I had this same problem with Vagrant the other day, something about TTY but I was also using Git Bash, maybe regular Windows CMD will fix that as well.

Comment: I have seen the same issue with Git Bash before. I do not use or know about Windows much so no idea. But people have suggested using `bash.exe` often works, instead of `git-bash.exe`. It has something to do with not including `winpty` or something.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows CMD console you should do this steps (if you use virtual environment):

1. c:\Path_to_you_App\venv\Scripts\activate
2. (venv) cd c:\Path_to_you_App
3. (venv) c:\Path_to_you_App>python manage.py createsuperuser

Answer (score 0):

You can create super user using:

```
winpty python manage.py createsuperuser
```